# how to get response from rest api callback call

Tags: php, json, rest, http

I have a sms api in php that i call to send sms. I pass some json and a url callback to get response status and the sms is sent.

Afterwards the server calls my callback url but i cannot get the response body. $_GET and $_POST are empty...
The documentation is non existing. It should have some json. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

```
    REQUEST_URI => /dev/egoi-resp.php
    GET => Array
    (
    )

    POST => Array
    (
    )

    SERVER => Array
    (
        [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
        [PWD] => /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys
        [SHLVL] => 0
        [SCRIPT_NAME] => /dev/egoi-resp.php
        [REQUEST_URI] => /dev/egoi-resp.php
        [QUERY_STRING] => 
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
        [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
        [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
        [REMOTE_PORT] => 45721
        [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/nchaves/public_html/dev/egoi-resp.php
        [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@nunochaves.com
        [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/nchaves/public_html
        [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
        [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
        [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/nchaves/public_html
        [REMOTE_ADDR] => 94.46.251.59
        [SERVER_PORT] => 80
        [SERVER_ADDR] => 185.11.164.13
        [SERVER_NAME] => nunochaves.com
        [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
        [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
        [LD_LIBRARY_PATH] => /usr/local/apache/lib
        [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 166
        [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
        [HTTP_HOST] => nunochaves.com
        [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Java/1.7.0_25
        [HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/json
        [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json
        [UNIQUE_ID] => VFeXf7kLpA0AB@tWLxMAAADG
        [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
        [PHP_SELF] => /dev/egoi-resp.php
        [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1415026559.7367
        [REQUEST_TIME] => 1415026559
    )
```

Comment: we can not help you, since we do not know what your API does. Without documentation or code, how should we know, what the API need to do?

Comment: The api is https://www51.e-goi.com/doc/index#method.public.webhooks.addSmsHook

Comment: Of course you get back nothing, documentation says: `Returns: void`

Comment: I add a webhook url for sms send and it gets called after an sms is sent / changes status. My trouble is how to get the response from that call in PHP.

Comment: void is returned when i add a webhook. That is done only once.

Comment: When you send an SMS, then it says, it will gives you back `The ID of the created message` in integer. After that i think you need to use the `dailyprefix` i guess, but i am not sure. I can not help you, because i do not know this API, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the hole webhook thing working. the only trouble was to grad the json answer when the hook was called.
I managed to find the answer.

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Comment: Hi @Jupiter We have tried the above code but its giving an empty result

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

```
url (string)
The URL that will be used for the Hook

actions (list)
The list of actions for which this hook is triggered.
Acceptable values: PROCESSED, SENT, DELIVERED, FAILED, CANCELED,
```

This URL will be used as the callback when a hook is triggered for the events you subscribed. So, lets imagine you subscribe to the `SENT` hook with the url `http://foo.org/foo.php`.

The hook related data will be sent (`POST`'ed) to the url -> `http://foo.org/foo.php`.

To see the received data I would go with this (naive) stub as a starting point:

```php
<?php
    $f = fopen('/tmp/hook.log', 'a+');
    $d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    fwrite($f, "------------- $d -----------\n");
    fwrite($f, print_r($_POST, true));
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Examine the `/tmp/hook.log` file (`tail -f /tmp/hook.log`) to see what is being sent.

Hope this helps,
Regards,
LL

Comment: your logic is corrected but the POST is empty. I managed to get the content using php input stram reader php://input. Thanks